# Pyspark collect list

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I am doing a group by over a column in a pyspark dataframe and doing a collect list on another column to get all the available values for column_1. As below.

```
Column_1 Column_2
A        Name1
A        Name2
A        Name3
B        Name1
B        Name2
C        Name1
D        Name1
D        Name1
D        Name1
D        Name1
```

The output that i get is a collect list of column_2 with column_1 grouped.

```
Column_1 Column_2
A        [Name1,Name2,Name3]  
B        [Name1,Name2]
C        [Name1]
D        [Name1,Name1,Name1,Name1]
```

Now when all the values within collect list are same, i just want to display it only once and not four times. Below is the expected output.

**Expected output:**

```
Column_1 Column_2
A        [Name1,Name2,Name3]  
B        [Name1,Name2]
C        [Name1]
D        [Name1]
```

Is there a way to do this in pyspark?

Comment: check `collect_set` instead of `collect_list` ..? or does order matter?

Comment: Yes. Order matters actually.

Comment: what kind of order is important ?, is it based on occurances? lets say if `Name1,Name3,Name2` is the sequence in group A , would the expected output be `Name1,Name2,Name3` or `Name1,Name3,Name2`

Comment: Its based on the order of occurance. Name1,Name2,Name3 should be maintained

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use **`collect_set`** to eliminate duplicates and use `array_sort`(From Spark-2.4.0) to sort the arrays.

- (or) use `array_distinct`(From Spark-2.4.0) to eliminate duplicates from collect_list.

---

```
df.show()
#+--------+--------+
#|Column_1|Column_2|
#+--------+--------+
#|       A|   Name1|
#|       A|   Name2|
#|       A|   Name3|
#|       B|   Name1|
#|       B|   Name2|
#|       C|   Name1|
#|       D|   Name1|
#|       D|   Name1|
#+--------+--------+

from pyspark.sql.functions import *    
df.groupBy('Column_1').agg(array_sort(collect_set(col('Column_2'))).alias("Column_2")).orderBy("Column_1").show(10,False)

#using array_distinct,array_sort functions   
df.groupBy('Column_1').agg(array_sort(array_distinct(collect_list(col('Column_2')))).alias("Column_2")).orderBy("Column_1").show(10,False)
#+--------+---------------------+
#|Column_1|Column_2             |
#+--------+---------------------+
#|A       |[Name1, Name2, Name3]|
#|B       |[Name1, Name2]       |
#|C       |[Name1]              |
#|D       |[Name1]              |
#+--------+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding to my comments above, if order matters in order of occurance (check input df):

```
+--------+--------+
|Column_1|Column_2|
+--------+--------+
|A       |Name1   |
|A       |Name3   | <-Name3 occurs first
|A       |Name2   |
|B       |Name1   |
|B       |Name2   |
|C       |Name1   |
|D       |Name1   |
|D       |Name1   |
|D       |Name1   |
|D       |Name1   |
+--------+--------+
```

you can first assign an index and the drop duplicates + collect list:

```
(df.withColumn("idx",F.monotonically_increasing_id()).dropDuplicates(["Column_1","Column_2"])
.orderBy("idx").groupby("Column_1").agg(F.collect_list("Column_2").alias("Column_2"))
 .orderBy("Column_1")).show(truncate=False)

+--------+---------------------+
|Column_1|Column_2             |
+--------+---------------------+
|A       |[Name1, Name3, Name2]|
|B       |[Name1, Name2]       |
|C       |[Name1]              |
|D       |[Name1]              |
+--------+---------------------+
```